# SOS, facing the black screen of death

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu

When I try to install Xubuntu from a live USB drive (which I checked is not corrupt), I get the "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported" message. However I figured out the usual hacks to make it boot but now it's giving the no init found error. All the answers on the net for resolving this involve starting from a system that  can boot properly, so I am at a loss to figure out what to do, and facing the proverbial black screen of death.

However I have to admit that the initial USB drive that I prepared wasn't checked for errors and only a second one was checked, but it gave the same errors.

I forgot to add that it's 18.04 that I was trying to install, since that was my original OS and my initial intention was to repair grub and everyone was saying that one had to reinstall.

Comment: Which hacks are you talking about? How did you copy the ISO to the USB drive? If you want to reinstall, why not the newer Xubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Comment: I created a new live 20.04 USB with Rufus and am still facing the same problem. Please help.

Comment: Try [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download) which writes the ISO raw to the disk (instructions [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/installation-media#windows)). [Rufus 3.10](https://rufus.ie/) claims to have "improved support for Ubuntu 20.04", don't know if that's true or which version you were using.

Comment: Tried what you said, but still facing the same problem.

Comment: I have to add that I made a lot of changes to the OS prior to all this since I was trying to configure an open VPN connection and was constantly facing problems which I was trying to troubleshoot using the various suggestions on the net and had finally succeeded in establishing a secure connection. But then as I was trying to configure the network manager I finally ran up against the problem of a defective grub which people were saying that it could be done only byreinstalling the system, which then started me on on this whole path.